# Notification clicked Callback

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, push-notification, android-notifications

I am trying to write a plugin for Unity3D to get the callback when a user clicks local or push notification when the app is closed. I tried Prime31 Etcetera Plugin for that but it doesn't work. So I decided to write my own plugin. I tried a couple of methods but it didn't work. Can anyone guide me how to do it ?

Answer (score 1):

I just had to do this a few days ago. Here's the class I used :

```
using System;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using UnityEngine.iOS;
using System.Collections;

public class Notifications : MonoBehaviour
{
    private void Awake()
    {
        // If app launched for the first time, set up a notification
        if (!PlayerPrefs.HasKey("firstLaunch"))
        {
            UnityEngine.iOS.NotificationServices.ClearLocalNotifications();
            UnityEngine.iOS.NotificationServices.CancelAllLocalNotifications();

            PlayerPrefs.SetInt("firstLaunch", 0);

            UnityEngine.iOS.NotificationServices.RegisterForNotifications(NotificationType.Alert | NotificationType.Badge | NotificationType.Sound);

            var notification = new UnityEngine.iOS.LocalNotification();
            notification.alertAction = "Title of the notification";
            notification.alertBody = "Body of the notification";
            // I set this to -1 because I didn't want to have the badge on the app icon
            notification.applicationIconBadgeNumber = -1;

            var currentDate = DateTime.Now;
            var targetDate = new DateTime(currentDate.Year, currentDate.Month, currentDate.Day, 9, 15, 00, DateTimeKind.Local);

            targetDate = (currentDate < targetDate) ? targetDate : targetDate.AddDays(1);

            // Set the date and time the notification will fire
            notification.fireDate = targetDate;
            // In my case in wanted to repeat it everyday at 9:15 AM
            notification.repeatInterval = UnityEngine.iOS.CalendarUnit.Day;

            UnityEngine.iOS.NotificationServices.ScheduleLocalNotification(notification);
        }
    }

    private void OnApplicationPause(bool state)
    {
        // If app returns to foreground
        if (!state)
        {
            // If this count > 0, then a notification has been clicked
            if (UnityEngine.iOS.NotificationServices.localNotificationCount > 0)
            {
                // Do stuff
            }

            UnityEngine.iOS.NotificationServices.ClearLocalNotifications();
        }

    }
}
```

Hope this helps !

Comment: This is for iOS , Unity provides notification service for iOS but not android. How can i achieve it in android ?

Comment: Oops my bad, didn't pay attention to the tags.. I never did it for Android, sorry. Maybe you could give a try to this plugin, it's free ! (https://github.com/Agasper/unity-android-notifications)